# Convert JPG images to PDF

Tags: geometry, pdfpages

I have multiple jpg files and I want to create a PDF with one image per page without any margin. Until now I used something like this and was enough because all images were the same size.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=0pt,paperheight=800mm,paperwidth=600mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\parindent=0pt
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
  \includepdf{Page_001.jpg}
  \includepdf{Page_002.jpg}
  \includepdf{Page_003.jpg}
  \includepdf{Page_004.jpg}
  \includepdf{Page_005.jpg}
  ...
\end{document}
```

Now I have pictures with different sizes and I want to create a PDF with pages having individual sizes according to each image size. Any idea how I can make this? Is there any way to set margin, width and height for \includepdf?

Comment: you mean you want each page exactly the size of the image? just use `graphicx` package and `\shipout\hbox{\includegraphics{file1.jpg}}\shipout\hbox{\includegraphics{file2.jpg}}\shipout\hbox{\includegraphics{file3.jpg}}...`

Comment: Why don't you use a tool for the purpose, like `img2pdf`?

Comment: Use the fitpaper option https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/509903/2388

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Works like a charm. Thank you.